# Reading (or parsing) corrupt PDF files (specifically SVID from SCO.com)

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, data-recovery

Is there a software, may be some very old versions, that can read a certain kind of corrupt PDF files?

Specifically, I'm collecting relic Unix specifications, and I want to read the System V Interface Definition from [SCO.com](http://www.sco.com/developers/devspecs/). The downloadable PDFs are corrupt and have rendering bugs.

Paid proprietary softwares are fine. I'm fine with macOS, Windows10, and GNU/Linux.

Comment: The first 3 (API) on that page all download and view find for me in Chrome - it is important to note that the spurious **looking** margin right margin annotations G, M, X, etc., actually denote which revision of the Unix specification, etc., that a change to that line was made. Some people are also not used to seeing the crop marks on the corners of each page.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I've spent some time reading it now, and I'm sure the content is incomplete. I downloaded the ones I have with Chrome and the reader didn't warn of corrupt data.

Comment: Particularly, the pages for the `poll` function is missing much of texts for possible pollable IO events.

Comment: Danny it is entirely possible that the files __uploaded__ to the site are incomplete or even that the entire documentation is incomplete. If the downloaded files don't complain about corruption then they are probably the same as the files on the site. Did you note that some of the specifications, e.g. AMD64 only include the differences from the Intel386. I would suggest contacting SCO for checksums on the files.